# Regular Expression for Alphabetical text with some exceptions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to for Regular Expression for a text field which accepts alphabets, also dots(.), brackets, -, & like

```
A.B.C
ABC (new),
A & A co.
A-abc.
```

I have my regular expression:

```
/^[A-z.&() ]+$/
```

**code:**

```
var regex = /^[a-z][a-z.()&-]+$/;
var sel = document.getElementById("TextBoxID").value;
if (sel != "-- Select --") {
if (!regex.test(sel.toString())) {
alert("Please use a proper name.");
}
} return false;
```

I want the string to mandatory start with alphabet.
But seems like this is not working when I add - into the same, may be the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that `[A-z]` is *not* the same as `[A-Za-z]`, which is probably what you meant. If you look at [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can see that the range from `A` to `z` includes several special characters that you may not intend to include.

Second, since the dash `-` denotes a *range* in a character class (as above), it must be included *last* (or first, but more commonly last) in order to be interpreted as a literal dash.

So, what you really want is this:

```
/^[A-Za-z.()&-]+$/
```

And to assert that it starts with an alphabet:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.()&-]*$/
  ^^^^^^^^             ^
```

(Notice I've changed the `+` quantifer to a `*` quantifier.)

Finally, as @ExplosionPills had done, you can simplify the expression by making it case-insensitive:

```
/^[a-z][a-z.()&-]*$/i
```

Comment: What was the need to replace + with *?

Comment: `+` means "1 or more". Since we're _requiring_ one character already, `[A-Za-z]`, we don't want to leave the `+` in `[A-Za-z.()&-]+`, because then you're requiring 2 or more characters in total. Changing it to `*` makes it require 1 or more characters in total.

Comment: @ItiTyagi - Then your problem is probably elsewhere. Could you edit your question to show more of your code? For example, how do you invoke the regex? And what is the exact string literal you're matching against? My blind guess is that maybe you're trying to find all instances in a single string with multiple instances, in which case you don't want to use the anchors, `^` and `$`, but even so, the solution depends on the format of your input.

Comment: @ItiTyagi - It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kjSDu/. (Try typing examples in the textbox.) I noticed you left a `+` in your pasted code; change it to a `*`. Also, you forgot the `i` at the end of the regex; you want this to be case-insensitive. Finally, if you want to include commas and spaces as allowable characters, use this instead: `/^[a-z][a-z.()&, -]*$/i`.